# Run a code in the GPU or parallelize somehow

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, gpu

I am running a NLP program in which I do a text preprocessing before running the main algorithms. The preprocessing is simple: I have an array of very long strings (around 20K words each string, 30K strings in total). I want to tokenize on each string with `nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer`:

```
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
from nltk import word_tokenize
import pandas as pd

    def tokenize_item(item):
        tokens = word_tokenize(item)
        stems = []
        for token in tokens:
            stems.append(PorterStemmer().stem(token))
        return stems

    def tokenize_text(text):
        return [' '.join(tokenize_item(txt.lower())) for txt in text]

text = pd.read_csv('texts.csv')['input_texts'].to_numpy()
tokenized_text = tokenize_text(text)
```

I want to either efficiently parallelize this process, or (preferably) run it on the GPU. Does anyone know how can I do either (or both) of these things?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have to use NLTK? If speed is what you're after, [SpaCy](https://spacy.io/) might be a better choice.

Comment: Nope! not necessarily! I can use whatever :)

Comment: Then I'd recommend you take a look at SpaCy, in particular the [pipe](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#processing) method which performs batching under the hood.

Comment: How could I do it with SpaCy?

Comment: I outlined the procedure in my answer below, please refer to it and the Quickstart guide on the SpaCy homepage. Everything else really depends on what you wanna do downstream :)

Comment: Please use the correct tags. This question has nothing to do with .NET's Task Parallel Library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where speed is a concern, [SpaCy](https://spacy.io/) is often preferable over NLTK. It offers both [batch processing](https://spacy.io/api/language#pipe) as well as [GPU integration](https://spacy.io/usage#gpu).

With an iterable of strings, this is the basic procedure of how you'd perform batch processing (note that there are a lot of options to tweak, like disabling certain parts of the pipeline that you don't need and setting a batch size, all of which is explained in detail in the SpaCy docs).

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf") # Or another model

docs = nlp.pipe(text) # with text being an iterable of strings
```

You will end up with a list of `doc` objects that have a lot of useful methods. It looks like you want a string with only the lemmas in lowercase, this is how you could do it:

```
def get_lemmas(doc):
    return ' '.join(tok.lemma_.lower() for tok in doc)

lemma_docs = (get_lemmas(doc) for doc in docs)
# lemma_docs = list(get_lemmas(doc) for doc in docs) # if you need all texts at once
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I replace the lists with generators?

Comment: I changed it to generators, it actually really makes sense here as long as you don't need anything else than the lemmatized strings. Otherwise you can always store the whole thing as a list via the last `list()` command. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! By the way, spacy doesn't find the web_trf package:

Comment: Okay! By the way, spacy doesn't find the trf package: OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_trf'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

Comment: Did you [download the model](https://spacy.io/models) via `python -m spacy download en_core_web_trf`?

Comment: It turns out that this approach is really slow.

Comment: It does need some tweaking and I'm afraid that usually means you need to go by trial and error... Check out [this blog post](https://prrao87.github.io/blog/spacy/nlp/performance/2020/05/02/spacy-multiprocess.html) for some inspiration.